# Подсчет каждого нажатия на кнопку PyQt5 Python

Tags: python, функции, pyqt5

Есть две кнопки `СТАРТ` и `РЕСЕТ`, а так же экран.
`СТАРТ` кнопка начинается с 1 и при каждом клике должна начаться подсчет.
Например: 4 раза кликаю на кнопку и в экране цифра 4 должна быть и так далее.

Подскажите, с чего начать.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    ...

        #Кнопка Старт. И привязка к функции start
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda:self.start(n=1))

    ...

    #Сама функция. Не знаю дальше что?
    def start (self, n):
        a=self.lineEdit.text()
        b=self.lineEdit.setText(a+str(n))

    ...


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для удобства сделал класс, описывающий виджет:

- Все нужные виджеты в нем (кнопки, метку для вывода текста)
- Хранение внутренних данных

Пример:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QPushButton, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.label = QLabel()
        self.label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        font = self.label.font()
        font.setPointSizeF(30)
        self.label.setFont(font)

        self.pb_add = QPushButton('ADD')
        self.pb_add.clicked.connect(self._on_add)

        self.pb_reset = QPushButton('RESET')
        self.pb_reset.clicked.connect(self._on_reset)

        self.number = 0

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        layout.addWidget(self.pb_add)
        layout.addWidget(self.pb_reset)

        self.setLayout(layout)
        
        self._update_states()

    def _update_states(self):
        self.label.setNum(self.number)

    def _on_add(self):
        self.number += 1
        self._update_states()

    def _on_reset(self):
        self.number = 0
        self._update_states()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])

    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()

    app.exec()
```

Скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Класс! Спасибо большое!

Comment: я бы предложил заменить `self.label.setText(str(self.number))` на `self.label.setNum(self.number)`

Comment: @S.Nick, хорошая идея, спасибо :)